# JavaScript: handle garbage collection

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I'm developing a javascript application in which I have some complex and heavy animations. These animations last few seconds then the system is idle to wait for user interaction and then, eventually, another animation starts.
Everything is OK except when the garbage collection happens DURING an animation... if it happens when the system is idle, then it is not performed during the animation and the animation is smooth. But if the GC happens during the animation I have some sloppy frames and the animation is not smooth.

Is there any way I can fix/enhance this? (avoid GC during animation and force to happen when system is idle).

Comment: No, you cannot force garbage collection in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes you can fix your memory usage.

Comment: memory is optimized as best as I could, I can have even 3 animations running one after the other without any GC...(it it has occourred just before the first animations started) but I cannot be sure that GC is never performed during an animation

Answer (score 0):

Perform your computations on [workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker), they are separate heaps and a GC pause in a worker should not impact the main (UI) thread.

If you're animating onto a canvas you can also use [OffscreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas) to do rendering work on different threads.